# __init__ in ABC abstract class in Python

Tags: python

In the below example, do I need to call the `super().__init__()` from the MySQLdatabase class or it is not needed?

If I override the `__init__` in the MySQLdatabase then it is my understanding that the `__init__` of the super class is not called anymore. Does this mean that the `__init__` of the ABC class is not called?

```
class Database(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def open_db_connection(self):
        pass
```

```
class MySQLdatabase(Database):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db_connection = None
        self.db_cursor = None
        self.record = None
        self.record_dict = None


    def open_db_connection(self) -> tuple[MySQLConnection, MySQLCursor]:
        try:
            self.db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                                                    host=HOST,
                                                    user=USERNAME,
                                                    password=PASSWORD,
                                                    port=PORT,
                                                    database=DATABASE_SCHEMA
            )
            if self.db_connection.is_connected():
                self.db_cursor = self.db_connection.cursor(prepared=True, dictionary=True)
                return self.db_connection, self.db_cursor
        except mysql.connector.Error as e:
            raise DatabaseException("error", f"while connecting to db: Database Connection Failed! error: {e}")
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Database` does not have an `__init__` method, then you do not need to call `super().__init__` in its subclasses.  But including the call does no harm, and protects you if you later *do* add an `__init__` method to the subclass.

Comment: I know I don't have an `__init__` in the Database class. but when I create an instance of MySQLdatabase how would it reach the `__init__` of the ABC class if from the `__init__`  in MySQLdatabase class I'm not calling the super() ?

Comment: You don't need to call `ABC.__init__()`.  Its sole purpose is to assign a metaclass to the current class.  It does not initialization.